# Is it possible to restrict access to some features and other apps using configuration profile?

Tags: ios, configuration-profiles

The goal is how to prevent user from using social media or texting while driving by simply plugging into `Special` cable?

Is it possible at all?

[Configuration profile Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW4)

Some questions:

1. Is there a way to disable or enable access to other apps or features using `Configuration Profile`?
2. Is it possible to turn it on/off via simple plugging phone into the `Special` cable?
3. Will app have possibility to install such profile on iPhone?

Comment: What do you mean by a "`Special` cable"?

Comment: I mean cable as a accessory with MFI certificate...